# I have a deadline is 5 days I need to add +1 day for each non-working days (weekend or holiday)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a rule, where I have a deadline is 5 days I need to add +1 day for each non-working days (weekend or holiday). also holidays of the following table reminding that if the final day can not be weekend or holiday...

My Table Holiday

[image]

I've tried it anyway but I can not get a good result

```
//The function returns the no. of business days between two dates and it skips the holidays
function getWorkingDays($startDate,$endDate,$holidays){
    // do strtotime calculations just once
    $endDate = strtotime($endDate);
    $startDate = strtotime($startDate);


    //The total number of days between the two dates. We compute the no. of seconds and divide it to 60*60*24
    //We add one to inlude both dates in the interval.
    $days = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;

    $no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
    $no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);

    //It will return 1 if it's Monday,.. ,7 for Sunday
    $the_first_day_of_week = date("N", $startDate);
    $the_last_day_of_week = date("N", $endDate);

    //---->The two can be equal in leap years when february has 29 days, the equal sign is added here
    //In the first case the whole interval is within a week, in the second case the interval falls in two weeks.
    if ($the_first_day_of_week <= $the_last_day_of_week) {
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 6 && 6 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 7 && 7 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
    }
    else {
        // (edit by Tokes to fix an edge case where the start day was a Sunday
        // and the end day was NOT a Saturday)

        // the day of the week for start is later than the day of the week for end
        if ($the_first_day_of_week == 7) {
            // if the start date is a Sunday, then we definitely subtract 1 day
            $no_remaining_days++;

            if ($the_last_day_of_week == 6) {
                // if the end date is a Saturday, then we subtract another day
                $no_remaining_days++;
            }
        }
        else {
            // the start date was a Saturday (or earlier), and the end date was (Mon..Fri)
            // so we skip an entire weekend and subtract 2 days
            $no_remaining_days += 2;
        }
    }

    //The no. of business days is: (number of weeks between the two dates) * (5 working days) + the remainder
    //---->february in none leap years gave a remainder of 0 but still calculated weekends between first and last day, this is one way to fix it
   $workingDays = $no_full_weeks * 5;
    if ($no_remaining_days > 0 )
    {
      $workingDays += $no_remaining_days;
    }

    //We subtract the holidays
    foreach($holidays as $holiday){
        $time_stamp=strtotime($holiday->data);
        //If the holiday doesn't fall in weekend
        if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && date("N",$time_stamp) != 6 && date("N",$time_stamp) != 7)
            $workingDays++;
    }

    return $workingDays;
}
```

Comment: Do you have database in your application?

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Stack Overflow! In your example you've provided a lot of code. Try to simplify it into a [MCVE]. The more you simplify your question, the easier it will be for us to help you, though as things stand you've given us a lot of code to sift through to try to figure out what is going on. Also please explain what you mean by "have not been able to get a good result". Are you getting error messages? Wrong output? Share with us what output you are getting, it'll make the error easier to find.

Comment: strtotime(date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "$startDate +".(1+getWorkingDays($startDate, $endDate, $holidays))." days" ))) 
returning the day 2018-01-02 this day is a holiday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DateTime` and `DateInterval` you can add a number of business days to a start date, with an optional array of holidays:

```
function getDeadline($start_date, $working_days, array $holiday_dates = array())
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start_date);
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // one day
    $holiday_dates = array_flip($holiday_dates); // so we can use isset to check for holidays
    while (
        $date->format('N') >= 6 // weekend day
        || isset($holiday_dates[$date->format('Y-m-d')]) // OR holiday
        || $working_days-- > 0 // OR deadline working days left to add
    ) {
        $date->add($interval); // move to next day
    }
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Testing as follows:

```
var_dump(getDeadline('2017-12-21', 5)); // only weekends
var_dump(getDeadline('2017-12-21', 5, array('2017-12-22', '2017-12-26'))); // weekends and holidays
```

Gives output:

```
string(10) "2017-12-28"
string(10) "2018-01-01"
```

As your holidays are stored in mysql, you could use a function like this to extract them in a single query:

```
function getHolidays($start_date)
{
    $database = new PDO(/* your connection details here */);
    $statement = $database->prepare("
        SELECT DISTINCT date
        FROM holiday
        WHERE date >= :start_date
        ORDER BY date ASC;
    ");
    $statement->bindValue(':start_date', $start_date);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
```

Assuming the `holidays` table exists as in your question, you can combine these functions to get the deadline date:

```
$holidays = getHolidays('2017-12-21');
var_dump($holidays);
$deadline_end_date = getDeadline('2017-12-21', 5, $holidays);
var_dump($deadline_end_date);
```

Gives output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2017-12-22"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2017-12-26"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2017-12-27"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2018-01-01"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2018-01-02"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2018-01-03"
}
string(10) "2018-01-05"
```